# Failed to look up view in views directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have defined

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

inside app.js , the structure of my project looks like

```
app.js
routes
views
  final
    finalFile.jade
```

i am using

```
res.render('final/finalFile',{
    var_one: one,
    var_two: two, 
    var_six: six
},function(err,html){
    if( err )
       console.log(err)

});
```

inside file located in routes directories

However it keeps complaining and throwing error

Failed to lookup view "final/finalFiler" in views directory , the path should be correct.

Did i overlook something? Why does it keep throwing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```
app.js
routes
 test.js
views
  final
    finalFile.jade
```

app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var path = require('path');
var test = require('./routes/test');    
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.get('/', test.helloWorld);
app.listen(1234);
```

test.js

```
exports.helloWorld = function(req, res) {
  res.render('final/finalFile', {
    var_one: 'one',
    var_two: 'two',
    var_six: 'six'
  });
};
```

finalFile.jade

```
p hello World
```

GET request on localhost:1234 renders

```
<p>hello World</p>
```